# Case Statement with comparison

Tags: mysql, sql

In the existing statement below I am comparing the host_name and ip_adress with records retrieved from an other table  and mark the column as true when found, but I would like to tweak it to give a true result when the host_name is also a part of identifer from the record retrieved
i.e

```
host_name=abc
identifier=abc.google.com should also be true

CASE
    WHEN
        (
            (`inv_y`.`host_name` <> '')
            AND
            `inv_y`.`host_name` IN (SELECT `inv_x`.`identifier`
                                      FROM `inv_x`
                                  ORDER BY `inv_x`.`creation_date` DESC
                                   )
        )
        OR
        (
            (`inv_y`.`ip_address` <> '')
            AND
            inv_y`.`ip_address` IN (SELECT `inv_x`.`identifier`
                                      FROM `inv_x`
                                  ORDER BY `inv_x`.`creation_date` DESC
                                   )
        )
    THEN
        'True'
    ELSE
        'False'
END
```

Comment: Please explain a bit more about what you are trying to achieve here ?

Comment: sample data and output is helpful

Comment: Indentation matters with code like this, what you pasted in here is extremely difficult to read.  So I've  changed the layout to be more readable.

Comment: Your "question" doesn't describe what issues you're facing, or actually ***ask a question***...  Why doesn't what you're shown us work?  What should it do and what does it actually do?  Can you demonstrate the problem with examples?   https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: @MatBailie Issue I am facing is it is not matching partial match for the identifier

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you could benefit from the `EXISTS` function. Something like the following could work:

```
SELECT CASE WHEN EXISTS(SELECT 1 
          FROM inv_y 
          WHERE (ip IN (SELECT identifier 
                       FROM inv_x)
          OR hostname IN (SELECT identifier 
                       FROM inv_x))
          AND hostname LIKE '%eb%'
         ) = 1 THEN "True"
  ELSE "False"
END AS Present;
```

Here's a demo of this working: [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/214eb6/30)

Note, the above could be simplified further if you can work with a 1 or 0 instead of true or false. `EXISTS` returns a 1 if the row is found, and 0 if not, and the `CASE` is there simply to translate this into 'True' or 'False', so you could simply have the following:

```
SELECT EXISTS(SELECT 1 
              FROM inv_y 
              WHERE (ip IN (SELECT identifier 
                            FROM inv_x)
                OR hostname IN (SELECT identifier 
                                FROM inv_x)
              )
              AND hostname LIKE '%eb%') AS Present;
```